# Changing the size of a table/Checkbox

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I am currently trying to get a Options Menu working in libGDX using scene2d.
For this i have a table, that contains 2 checkbox.

```
 private Table buildCheckBoxLayer(){
    Table table = new Table();
    table.center();

    //+ Checkbox Music
    checkBoxMusic = new CheckBox(" Music ",skinGUIoptionsUI);
    table.add(checkBoxMusic);


    table.row();

    //+ Checkbox Sound
    checkBoxSound = new CheckBox(" Sound",skinGUIoptionsUI);
    table.add(checkBoxSound);

    table.setDebug(debugMode);
    return table;
}
```

First code shows the building of the table and the checkboxes, and the following code shows how its implemented in the stage

```
 //Checkboxes + labels
    Table checkBoxLayer = buildCheckBoxLayer();
    stack.addActor(checkBoxLayer);
```

It all works fine, the only problem is, that the checkboxes are really small. Ive tried multiple things to get them smaller, but nothing worked. The checkboxes stayed the same size, regardless of what i changed: The size of the Checkboxes, the size of the row, the checkboxes are in, the size of the table and so on. So how can i make these things bigger?

Comment: Maybe set size for your table and then expand() and fill() the checkboxes.